# What can i do to not re-run gradle spring boot application again and again

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I've one gradle spring boot project. Even if i'd to put one log at some place. It requires re-run of the application. Is there anyway to add these type of changes on the fly when application is running (on my local system).

Answer (score 0):

For some cases, hot reload which is JVM feature should do the trick